# How to chain tasks within each thread

Tags: c#-4.0, progress-bar, task-parallel-library, chain

I have a requirement for copying several hundred tables using bulkcopy.
So far I got the following code.

```
// from UI main thread
private void test1()
{
  LimitedTaskScheduler scheduler = new LimitedTaskScheduler(4);
  TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);
  foreach (DataRow row in tabList.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
  {
    string tabName = row[tabList.Columns["TableName"]].ToString();
    factory.StartNew<string>( () =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} on thread {1}", tabName, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
      TableCopyer tc1 = new TableCopyer();
      // pass progressbar and label into tc1 instance to update the progressbar and label
      tc1.Bar1 = bar1; 
      tc1.L1 = l1;
      tc1.EntityCopy(AppInfo.SrcDBMSPath, AppInfo.DestDBMSPath, tabName, "");
      return tabName;
    });
  }
}

// inside TableCopier class
private void OnSqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    int rowCopied = int.Parse(e.RowsCopied.ToString());
    double result = (double.Parse(rowCopied.ToString()) / double.Parse(TotalRows.ToString()));
    int prsent = int.Parse(Math.Round((result * 100), 0).ToString());
    SetProgressbar(prsent);
  }
  catch { throw; }
}
```

LimitedTaskScheduler is coming from 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx

My questions are

1. How do I chain the tasks so that each will start only upon the finish of the prior task within each thread? I limited the max parallel thread to 4. I want to chain the tasks within the threads because the tasks being performed within a thread will reuse the same progressbar in a way one finishes and another starts.
2. I have 4 progress bar painted on UI, bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4. How do I associate each progressbar with a particular thread so that the user can see 4 running progress at the same time?

Comment: Note: The progressbars are used to report the progress for each bulkcopy operation (per table). for example updated for every 5 thousand rows based on the NotifyAfter event. The user want to see the progress for each table/task.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't make much sense to tie yourself into thinking about specific threads. Instead, what you want is that your tasks run concurrently at most 4 at a time and you want to use your 4 progress bars from those tasks.

What you could do is to put those progress bars into a collection, and then take a progress bar from there at the start of each task and return it back there at the end of the task.

You have to be careful about thread-safety here, so you should either use locks when working with the collection of progress bars, or use a thread-safe collection like `ConcurrentQueue`. Also, updating the progress bar usually has to be done from the UI thread, so you will have to take care of that too.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I chain the tasks so that each will start only upon the finish
>   of the prior task within each thread? I limited the max parallel
>   thread to 4. I want to chain the tasks within the threads because the
>   tasks being performed within a thread will reuse the same progressbar
>   in a way one finishes and another starts.

You want to chain your tasks together.  So essentially there is no parallel processing occurring, except that you wish to process this on a thread separate to the UI.  So, why then do you want to spawn a new task for each iteration of your loop if you wan't your loop processing to run sequentially?  You could just wrap a normal for loop in a task:

```
private void test1()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in tabList.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
        {
            string tabName = row[tabList.Columns["TableName"]].ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("{0} on thread {1}", tabName, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            TableCopyer tc1 = new TableCopyer();
            // pass progressbar and label into tc1 instance to update the progressbar and label
            tc1.Bar1 = bar1;
            tc1.L1 = l1;
            tc1.EntityCopy(AppInfo.SrcDBMSPath, AppInfo.DestDBMSPath, tabName, "");
        }
    });
}
```

> I have 4 progress bar painted on UI, bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4. How do I
>   associate each progressbar with a particular thread so that the user
>   can see 4 running progress at the same time?

There are many ways to do this and it really depends on your requirements as to which is the best.  You could reference the progress bars in a `Queue<T>`, but only if you are convinced that you will have as many progress bars as you have table rows.

```
private void test1()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var progressBars = new Queue<ProgressBar>(new List<ProgressBar> { bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4 });

        foreach (DataRow row in tabList.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
        {
            // ...

            if(progressBars.Count() == 0}
                throw new Exception("Not enough progress bars setup!");

            tc1.Bar1 = progressBars.Dequeue();

            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

If `tabList.Rows` is an `IEnumerable`, then you can ensure that the queue won't break by using `Take()`:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tabList.Rows.Take(progressBars.Count()))
{ ... }
```

Comment: “essentially there is no parallel processing occurring, except that you wish to process this on a thread separate to the UI” That's not how I understood the question. The OP wants to chain the `Task`s within each of the 4 threads. And regarding the progressbars, I think each one of them is supposed to show the progress in one of the 4 threads, it certainly shouldn't be tied to one row forever.

Comment: Svick interpreted my question correctly. I do want parallel processing. I would like one progressbar to be tied to each thread. So the thread in relation to progressbar is 1-to-1. And within each thread the task should be chained so that each task can show its own progress in the progressbar that is tied to the thread inside which the task is running.

Comment: Ah, apologies!  But when you say you want the tasks "chained", don't you mean that you want them to run one after another?  Like a continuation?

Comment: for example, 40 tables all together. 4 threads thread_1 process 10 tables, thread_2 process another 10 tables the chain should happen within a thread, i.e. chained within thread_1 and chained within thread_2, and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: Further thought. Perhaps chaining is not necessary. the real purpose is to let each thread to be associated with a progress bar so that it behaves like this: thread1 get task1 and finds that progressbar1 is available. then it uses progressbar1 to display the progress of task1. Upon finish thread1 receives another task, say task6, and it finds progressbar4 is available, then it uses progressbar4 to display the progress of task 6. But I could not find a way to do this.